# gsutill: backup files that encrypted with Customer-Supplied Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google cloud storage bucket containing files. *Each of these files is encrypted with a different key*, for security reasons. This bucket is the source. I want to copy it's content from the Source bucket to the Destination bucket. Just to have a backup...

I tried to run this command:

```
$ gsutil cp -r gs://source-bucket/* gs://dest-bucket/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 132, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 431, in main
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 760, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    _HandleUnknownFailure(e)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 626, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 411, in RunNamedCommand
    return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1200, in RunCommand
    seek_ahead_iterator=seek_ahead_iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1515, in Apply
    arg_checker, should_return_results, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1586, in _SequentialApply
    worker_thread.PerformTask(task, self)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 2306, in PerformTask
    results = task.func(cls, task.args, thread_state=self.thread_gsutil_api)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 790, in _CopyFuncWrapper
    preserve_posix=cls.preserve_posix_attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1000, in CopyFunc
    preserve_posix=preserve_posix)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 3729, in PerformCopy
    decryption_key = GetDecryptionCSEK(src_url, src_obj_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 3645, in GetDecryptionCSEK
    (src_obj_metadata.customerEncryption.keySha256, src_url))
gslib.cloud_api.EncryptionException: Missing decryption key with SHA256 hash 0z1dPrWjTL6yrU5U6GP2gTaBriwNbMJnh6CcIuLSy8o=. No decryption key matches object gs://source-bucket/myfile.json
```

I guess that the reason for this failure is the missing key in order to copy the files.

I also tried to create a Transfer operation but it failed for a strange reason.

How I can back up my files in this case? Just copy it as is. 
What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply the keys that you used to encrypt the files. 
With gsutils you have to use the .boto file and put inside something similar:

```
[GSUtil]
encryption_key = ...
decryption_key1 = ...
decryption_key2 = ...
```

> gsutil automatically detects the correct CSEK to use for a cloud
>   object by comparing the key's SHA256 hash against the hash of the
>   CSEK. gsutil considers the configured encryption key and up to 100
>   decryption keys when searching for a match. Decryption keys must be
>   listed in the boto configuration file in ascending numerical order
>   starting with 1.

for more on customer-supplied encryption keys check [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/UsingEncryptionKeys)

Comment: If the bucket has 1M files, it will be a hard thing to handle this keys file. Anyway, this sound strange since copying the file between different google buckets doesn't expose the file content. In contrast to copy file from the bucket to the local machine (even in that way, the file can be downloaded encrypted).